# Generic type 'TextField' requires arguments in form

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following form:

```
struct RentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: RentViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: RentViewModel){
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var textField : TextField

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Enter total rent")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)) {
                    TextField("Total rent", text: $viewModel.amount.totalRent)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

                }
                Section(header: Text("Enter total bills?")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)) {
                    TextField("Total bills", text: $viewModel.amount.totalBills)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

                }
                Section(header: Text("Enter wages?")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)) {
                    TextField("Your monthly wage", text: $viewModel.amount.myMonthlyIncome)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                Section(header: Text("What are the wages of your housemates?")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.incomes.indices){
                        index in TextField("Housemate \(index + 1)", text: $viewModel.incomes[index])
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Your share: £\(viewModel.yourShare, specifier: "%.2f")")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 22, design: .default))
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }.foregroundColor(Color.red)
                if textField != nil && !textField.hasText {
                    Text("Please fill in all sections")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This calculates the rent equally between housemates based on income. However it will only update if all of the forms are filled in. Therefore I want a message to pop up saying "Please fill in all sections" (as above in last section) if one text field has been left empty. However I am getting the error: "Reference to generic type 'TextField' requires arguments in <...>" I am very new to Swift and am not sure what arguments are required here and why?

My Rent View Model looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class RentViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var amount: Amounts
    @Published var incomes: [String]
    
    init(_ amount: Amounts, housemates: Int){
        self.amount = amount
        self.incomes = Array(repeating: "", count: housemates)
    }
    
    var myMonthlyIncome : String { return amount.myMonthlyIncome }
    var housemateMonthlyIncome : String { return amount.housemateMonthlyIncome }
    var totalRent : String { return amount.totalRent }
    var totalBills : String { return amount.totalBills }
    
    var yourShare: Double {
        guard let totalRent = Double(totalRent) else { return 0 }
        guard let totalBills = Double(totalBills) else {return 0 }
        guard let myMonthlyIncome = Double(myMonthlyIncome) else { return 0 }
        let incomesInt = incomes.compactMap { Int($0) }
        let housemateMonthlyIncome = Double(incomesInt.reduce(0, +))
        let totalIncome = Double(myMonthlyIncome + housemateMonthlyIncome)
        let percentage = myMonthlyIncome / totalIncome
        let householdTotal = totalRent + totalBills
        let value = (householdTotal * percentage)

        return (round(100*value)/100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code? Minimal, Reproducible Example is needed so we an replicate your issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is something with misfit types in model and bindings. Would you show RentViewModel and internals?

Comment: @Asperi I have updated to show RentViewModel

Comment: It is due to `var textField : TextField` and related - remove all that - it is incorrect and make condition also based on `viewModel`

Comment: Thanks @Asperi - what do you mean make the condition based on `viewModel`?